# How to return listObjectsV2 as json

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

I'm trying to call the AWS S3 Bucket and get my list of image URLs but it's not retrieving it.

I'm using Express for the back end and React for the front end. When i manually enter static data for the array of JSON it does show on the server. I'm using listObjectsV2 to get the list

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new aws.S3({
    accessKeyId: "secretId",
    secretAccessKey: "secretKey",
    region : 'eu-west-2',
    Bucket: 'my-aws-bucket'
});

let params = {
    Bucket: "my-aws-bucket", 
    MaxKeys: 6
};

app.get('/api/images', (req, res) => {
    let images = [];


s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } else { 

        var href = this.request.httpRequest.endpoint.href;
        var bucketUrl = href + "my-aws-bucket" + '/';

        data.Contents.map(function(photo) { 
            var photoKey = photo.Key;
            var photoUrl = bucketUrl + encodeURIComponent(photoKey);
            images.push(photoUrl);
        }); 
    }
});  

res.json(images);

});

const port = 5001; 
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is on port: ${port}`));
```

i expected my images empty array that i declared to be filled with image URL such as
[https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-aws-bucket/images/image1.png,https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-aws-bucket/images/image2.png]

However nothing is being filled in the array. If i manually add stuff into the images array like let images = [1,2,3,4]; then when i go to http://localhost:5001/api/images it does show the [1,2,3,4], but nothing with the code above that should work.

Comment: Are you getting `photo.Key` correctly? And also you can use a simple `forEach` instead of a `map` function

Comment: hey @DragonBorn, yes I am. This is what data.Contents returns:

Contents:
   [ { Key: 'aws.png',
       LastModified: 2019-06-04T09:55:27.000Z,
       ETag: '"74d4c1e312c30cd029ee7d10620c9b66"',
       Size: 18156,
       StorageClass: 'STANDARD' },
     { Key: 'images/',
       LastModified: 2019-06-04T09:55:11.000Z,
       ETag: '"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"',
       Size: 0,
       StorageClass: 'STANDARD' }];

Comment: can you `console.log` your images array after pushing items into it, outside of your loop and check it.

Comment: hey @DragonBorn , I worked it out, i just had to simply move the 
res.json(images); just after the closing else{}

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out in the end, i just had to simply move the 
res.json(images); just after the closing else{}, so this is the fixed code

```
s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } else { 
    var href = this.request.httpRequest.endpoint.href;
    var bucketUrl = href + "my-aws-bucket" + '/';

    data.Contents.map(function(photo) { 
        var photoKey = photo.Key;
        var photoUrl = bucketUrl + encodeURIComponent(photoKey);
        images.push(photoUrl);
    }); 
   }
   res.json(images);

});
```